# Date picker format android

Tags: java, android

I am kind of stuck on my project.  I am asking for help on the `datepicker` format I managed to display my one on a TextView in full format.

However, after doing some coding in java, when I call in a date picker and pick a new date, it updates in short format, for example.

Current date `Friday, January, 20 2017` after using date picker it shows `20-1-17`

I want it to display in full, please help, below is my Java code

```
public class EntryEdit extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
int year_x, month_x, day_x;
static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry_edit);

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    showDialogOnTextViewClick();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(new Date());

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    textView.setText(currentDateString);

}

public void showDialogOnTextViewClick() {
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    if (id == DIALOG_ID)
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener, year_x, month_x, day_x);
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener
= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        year_x = year;
        month_x = month +1;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;

        String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(new Date());

        updateStartDisplay();


    }
};

private void updateStartDisplay() {
    textView.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(day_x + 1).append("-").append(month_x).append("-")
            .append(year_x).append(" "));

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your textView shows 20-1-2017 is because each time you pick a date in a DatePicker, you call `updateStartDisplay()` method, where you specifically set the text to be `day-month-year`.

Here's one possible solution:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        year_x = year;
        month_x = month;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year_x, month_x, day_x);
        String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
        textView.setText(currentDateString);

    }
};
```